# Two-transistor latch modified to include a second input and reset

Tags: batteries, relay, bms, lifepo4

(Rewritten from scratch and with a better starting point)
I want to use a separate battery to start my engine. It's a LiFePO4 battery so it has an electronic BMS to control charging & discharging to keep the state-of-charge in a safe range. Starting the engine draws hundreds of amps with an initial surge possibly in the 1 kA range. In the worst-case scenario, the BMS could decide to cut off the current while the current is high. I plan to use a [high-current relay](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=EV200_R_TBD_KILOVAC_EV200_Ser_Contactors&DocType=CS&DocLang=English) so the current won't flow through the BMS, so that's safe. However, the relay would have a short lifespan if it is used to break the circuit during the high current flow.

A few seconds of use won't put the battery health in danger, so I want to override the BMS while the current is high, allowing the motor to stop normally before disconnecting the relay. The BMS can refuse to let the process begin but cannot interrupt once the starter relay has engaged.

1. I think need to modify the standard two-transistor latch. I think that if I add an optocoupler upstream of Q2 it will act as both the required input and reset the latch when it goes low.
2. What components do I need to upgrade to handle the 3.8 A needed to engage the relay? Is it just Q2? I see a bunch of choices when I google "5A PNP transistor". Is there one everyone uses? How about that diode? It's a big coil.
3. It would be great if the relay could stay active for a fraction of a second after the key was turned off. I imagine a capacitor draining through a resistor. Where would I put that and what values am I looking at? The holding current for the relay is 0.13 A which seems like a lot. Probably best to do it upstream of the optocoupler?

[image: Modifications to this circuit.]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Good Bot.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "standard two-transistor latch"?

Comment: Nothing really.  Just that this circuit came up frequently when I was searching for a starting point.  First, second and fourth, but that could just be Google showing me what it thinks I want or my eye seeing patterns I recognize.  Should I start somewhere else?

Comment: More "standard" is a latch made with two NPN transistors. See for example this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/617512/61398) and this [movie](https://photos.app.goo.gl/59vK5Yn5pwmvBhjr8).